# Argo HTTP workflow - failed to get token volumes: service account argo/default does not have any secrets

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I am new to Argo and following the Quickstart templates and would like to deploy the HTTP template as a workflow.

I create my cluster as so:

```bash
minikube start --driver=docker --cpus='2' --memory='8g'
kubectl create ns argo
kubectl apply -n argo -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/manifests/quick-start-postgres.yaml
```

I then apply the HTTP template `http_template.yaml` from the docs:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: http-template-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: get-google-homepage
            template: http
            arguments:
              parameters: [ { name: url, value: "https://www.google.com" } ]
    - name: http
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: url
      http:
        timeoutSeconds: 20 # Default 30
        url: "{{inputs.parameters.url}}"
        method: "GET" # Default GET
        headers:
          - name: "x-header-name"
            value: "test-value"
        # Template will succeed if evaluated to true, otherwise will fail
        # Available variables:
        #  request.body: string, the request body
        #  request.headers: map[string][]string, the request headers
        #  response.url: string, the request url
        #  response.method: string, the request method
        #  response.statusCode: int, the response status code
        #  response.body: string, the response body
        #  response.headers: map[string][]string, the response headers
        successCondition: "response.body contains \"google\"" # available since v3.3
        body: "test body" # Change request body
```

`argo submit -n argo http_template.yaml --watch`

However I get the the following error:

```
Name:                http-template-564qp
Namespace:           argo
ServiceAccount:      unset (will run with the default ServiceAccount)
Status:              Error
Message:             failed to get token volumes: service account argo/default does not have any secrets
```

I'm not clear on why this doesn't work given it's straight from the Quickstart documentation. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your default serviceaccount is missing a credential (kubernetes secret)

You can verify the existence of the credential by checking which one it needs by running
`kubectl get serviceaccount -n default default -o yaml`

```
kubectl get serviceaccount -n default default -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-10T10:48:54Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "*******"
  uid: ********************
secrets:
- name: default-token-*****
```

Now you should be able to find the secret which is attached to the serviceaccount

`kubectl get secret -n default default-token-***** -o yaml`

Or you can just run

`kubectl get secret -n default`

To see all secrets in the respective namespace (in this example, default)

Answer (score 1):

The post-1.24 documentation regarding this is:

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/manually-create-secrets/

The easiest option is the first one: create a secret with a specific name.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: default.service-account-token
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Answer (score 0):

Argo Workflows does not yet work with Kubernetes v1.24+. See this issue:

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/8320